# Run Jasmine tests after initial function calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jasmine

I'm writing Jasmine tests for a Node.js API.  I'm trying to test the create a user functionality.  The test would look like this:

```
describe('User test', function() {
  describe('Post /api/saveUser'), function() {
    it('saves a new user', function(done) {
      request.post({url: 'http://website/api/saveUser', form:{email:testU.email, password:testU.password}, headers: {'authorization': adminU.jwt}}, function(err, res, body) {
        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

So I need to authenticate the admin user (adminU) in the spec to get the valid token to pass in the request.  This is done using another endpoint.

```
request.post({url: 'http://website/api/authenticate', form:{email:adminU.email, password: adminU.password}}, function(err, res, body) {
  adminUser.jwt = JSON.parse(res.body).token;
});
```

But how do I combine these.  If I slot the authentication code above the User test block, the user tests are run before the response from the authentication endpoint is received.  The obvious choice is to wrap the user tests in the callback from the authenticate api, but then when I run the tests Jasmine doesn't actually run them.

What's the best way to use the results of a callback in the Jasmine specs?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344872/testing-asynchronous-callbacks-with-jasmine

Comment: Thanks, that does help. Putting the authentication in the "it" function with a `done()` means the authentication happens first which is good.  Is it possible to move it right out of the "it" spec though so all other tests have access to the data to save making an auth call for every spec?  Or is that bad practice/not possible?

Comment: I am not really sure, I have only recently started using Jasmine. All I did was a quick google. Here are another couple of interesting links: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/stips/using-jasmine-2.0s-new-done-function-to-test-asynchronous-processes.html, http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/test-asynchronous-methods-using-the-jasmine-runs-and-waitfor-methods.html#fbid=IkUosnCZw2O basically searched for jasmine async testing

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until the request of the auth call is finished.

```
it('saves a new user', function(done) {
    request.post({
        url: 'http://website/api/authenticate',
        form: {
            email: adminU.email,
            password: adminU.password
        }
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        adminUser.jwt = JSON.parse(res.body).token;
        request.post({
            url: 'http://website/api/saveUser',
            form: {
                email: testU.email,
                password: testU.password
            },
            headers: {
                'authorization': adminU.jwt
            }
        }, function(err, res, body) {
            expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

If you need the token in more then one test, i would recommend to put it in the before block. If you do this, jasmine runs this once before starting the test and you don't have to make the auth call in every test case.

```
before(function(done){
    request.post({
        url: 'http://website/api/authenticate',
        form: {
            email: adminU.email,
            password: adminU.password
        }
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        if(err) done(err);
        adminUser.jwt = JSON.parse(res.body).token;
        done();
    });
});
```

Also, i recommend supertest for testing apis. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using Jasmine-node which doesn't have the before function unfortunately but this is compelling reason to switch to the latest standard Jasmine release.