# sqlite3 code does not run in jasmine

Tags: node.js, sqlite, jasmine

Has anyone ever tried to run sqlite3 code under the jasmine testing framework? For some reason, the same code can display table rows with node, but not under node running jasmine.

For example, this displays all rows in table [table_name]:

```
$ node src/test.js
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database("/home/user/test_db.sqlite3", 'OPEN_READ');
db.each("SELECT info FROM table_name", function(err, row) {
    console.log(row.info);
});
```

This same exact code under jasmine does not:

```
$ jasmine spec/TestSpec.js 
describe("Orders table", function() {
     it("should display all items in table [table_name]", function() {
        var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
        var db = new sqlite3.Database("/home/user/test_db.sqlite3", 'OPEN_READ');
        db.each("SELECT info FROM table_name", function(err, row) {
           console.log(row.info);
        });
     })
});
```

Does anyone know why it runs under one table but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the test asynchronously. Jasmine isn't waiting for the DB to connect and iterate. You can provide a [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344872/testing-asynchronous-callbacks-with-jasmine) to Jasmine to let it know that it's ok to run the test. Also, per the documentation, I had to supply sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY as the mode to make this work. Perhaps this is due to version changes.

```
describe("Orders table", function() {
    it("should display all items in table [table_name]", function(done) {
        var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
        var db = new sqlite3.Database("/home/user/test_db.sqlite3", sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY, function() {
            db.each("SELECT info FROM table_name", function(err, row) {
                console.log(row.info);
            }, done);
        });
    })
});
```