# Promises (from native ES 6 and jquery) are not resolved in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to test a promise with jasmine, I can write the promise in native javascript (with `Promise` constructor) or in jQuery (with `$.Deferred()` method). I cannot use angularJS.

When I try to resolve the promises in jasmine, the method associate to resolve event is never called. There are a lot of solution on stack-overflow related to angular promises, but I didn't find a solution for native or jQuery promises.

Here the test examples (I removed every code and I left just the part related to promises to me more synthetic):

```
describe('test native promises', function () {
    it('should resolve the promise', function () {
        var result;
        var promise = new Promise(function (callback) {
            callback({});
        });
        promise.then(function (response) {
            console.log('called 1');
            result = response;
        });
        Promise.resolve({}).then(function (response) {
            console.log('called 2');
            result = response;
        });
        expect(result).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

The `console.log` is never called and the `result` is undefined (so the test is failing).

The same issue in jQuery promises:

```
describe('test jQuery promises', function () {
    it('should resolve the promise', function () {
        var result;
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        deferred.promise().then(function (response) {
            console.log('called 3');
            result = response;
        });

        deferred.resolveWith({});

        expect(result).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

The variable `result` still undefined and the `console.log` never called.

This is an issue just in jasmine unit test, promises are working fine in browser (both versions).

I'm forgetting something in the unit test?

It was reported as [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344872/testing-asynchronous-callbacks-with-jasmine), but the issue is quite different, in this case the promises are not called at all.

Comment: `then` callbacks are *asynchronous*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I agree that they are asynchronous, but I'm expecting they are called directly when I use the `deferred.resolveWith` method or other method that let me force the resolve, the `then` should be called directly.

Also, I tried with `done` method, but the result does not change at all. The `console.log` is not called.

Comment: Your expectation that the `then` callback will be called "directly" is mistaken. It will not, because promises are meant to help us with *less* chaos, not more. `then` callbacks are **always** asynchronous.

Comment: The reason your code using `done` doesn't work is different: You're using [`resolveWith`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/) but should be using [`resolve`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/). `resolveWith`'s first parameter is the value to use as `this` during callbacks, so you're not passing a value for `response`. If you use `resolve`, and use `done`, because `done` is synchronous (e.g., broken :-) ), it will do what you're expecting.

Comment: Sorry @T.J.Crowder but I still don't understand how let it work: if I call the `done` method the test still pass also when I comment the `deferred.resolve` (or the equivalent method to resolve the promises). I'm trying to create a unit test that should fail if the promise does not resolve. How can I be sure that the method in `then` is called and with proper params?

Comment: If you want to use `then`, you use the asynchronous techniques described (with examples) in the Jasmine documentation referenced by the answer to the linked question.